# Any way i can output google spreadsheet last values?

Tags: excel, qt, google-apps-script, spreadsheet

I am doing a project like Real time display, I need read the last values of my spreadsheet on my google drive. I have no idea how to do it , I can not find any way to have google scripts to make the spreadsheet's last cell to send out. Anyone can help me out??
i will use qt program make as receiver .

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will give you the last row of data on your sheet.  You have to fill in the SpreadsheetID and SheetName;

```
function lastRowData()
{
   var ss=SpreadsheetApp.openById('SpreadsheetId');
   var sht=ss.getSheetByName('SheetName');
   var rng=sht.getDataRange();
   var values=rng.getValues();
   return values[values.length-1];

}
```

Comment: thanks your reply, one more thing is how can i output the values? I mean send out to another program in my computer??

Comment: After you give it the SpreadsheetId and SheetName then You can put it in a cell in another spread sheet like this `=lastRowData()` .  It will output the data and you can copy and paste it.

Comment: If you wouldn't mind, I'd appreciate it if you would check off my answer.